# Create an indicator variable in one data frame based on values in another data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, skimr

Say, I have a dataset called `iris`. I want to create an indicator variable called `sepal_length_group` in this dataset. The values of this indicator will be p25, p50, p75, and p100. For example, I want sepal_length_group to be equal to "p25" for an observation if the Species is "setosa" and if the `Sepal.Length` is equal to or less than the 25th percentile for all species classified as "setosa". I wrote the following codes, but it generates all NAs:

```
library(skimr)

sepal_length_distribution <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% skim(Sepal.Length) %>% select(3, 9:12)

iris_2 <- iris %>% mutate(sepal_length_group = ifelse(Sepal.Length <= sepal_length_distribution[which(sepal_length_distribution$Species == "setosa"),2], "p25", NA))

iris_2 <- iris %>% mutate(sepal_length_group = ifelse(Sepal.Length > sepal_length_distribution[which(sepal_length_distribution$Species == "setosa"),2] &
                                                Sepal.Length <= sepal_length_distribution[which(sepal_length_distribution$Species == "setosa"),3], "p50", NA))

iris_2 <- iris %>% mutate(sepal_length_group = ifelse(Sepal.Length > sepal_length_distribution[which(sepal_length_distribution$Species == "setosa"),3] &
                                                        Sepal.Length <= sepal_length_distribution[which(sepal_length_distribution$Species == "setosa"),4], "p75", NA))

iris_2 <- iris %>% mutate(sepal_length_group = ifelse(Sepal.Length > sepal_length_distribution[which(sepal_length_distribution$Species == "setosa"),4] &
                                                        Sepal.Length < sepal_length_distribution[which(sepal_length_distribution$Species == "setosa"),5], "p100", NA))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: So break into quantiles by group?

Comment: A few posts that should help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291876/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42948306/5325862

Comment: So you specifically want to use the skimr output?  When you say an indicator variable do you mean that you basically want an ordered factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done simply by the use of the function `cut` as commented by [@Camille](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612049/create-an-indicator-variable-in-one-data-frame-based-on-values-in-another-data-f#comment119507807_67612147)

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(cat = cut(Sepal.Length, 
                   quantile(Sepal.Length, c(0,.25,.5,.75, 1)),
                   paste0('p', c(25,50, 75, 100)), include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks. This solves this particular problem of mine. But I was thinking of a more general case where I may want to create an indicator variable that will be based on a particular cell in a different dataframe. That's why the reason why I tried to use `which`.